# European Call Option Modelling under 2 factor Hull White interest rates

Tags: programming, stochastic-processes, finance, hullwhite, financial-engineering

I have modelled the yield curve through the two factor Hull White Model. Now I want to implement in Matlab the price development of a ATM-Call-Option (European).
Has someone an idea how to combine them and which variables do I need in order to implement the Call Option price development.

Comment: It is not clear. What is the dynamics of the two-factor Hull White model? What is the payoff of your option (e.g., underlying, maturity)?

Comment: The dynamics is given by
$r(t) = x(t) + y(t) + \varphi(t), r(0)  = r_0 \\
dx(t)  = -a x(t) dt + \sigma dW_1(t), x(0)  = 0  \\
dy(t)  = -by(t) dt + \eta dW_2(t), y(0) = 0 \\$



From that we can derive the bond prices and calculate the yields. Underlying price is 8000 and maturity is 20 years from today.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Is $W_1$ and $W_2$ correlated? For the option, I meant whether it is a zero-coupon bond option? How long is the difference between the option maturity and the bond maturity?

Comment: thank you for your answer and help. Yes they are correlated: $dW_1(t)dW_2(t)  = \rho dt$.  It is a zero-coupon bond option with one year option maturity. The bond maturity is 20 years.